# Pagination Functionality using handlebars js

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, handlebars.js

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/syedazam/project/editor/XYeJoa/#0)**

I'am developing a Pagination Functionality using handlebars js and fetching the data from JSON.

1. First 5 results will be shown on page load.
2. on click of next pagination another set of 5 results will be displayed and so on.
3. If i have total number of results 100 by displaying each 5 Results in page. Page Numbers will be 1 of 20.
4. if the pagination has more then 5 number of Pages , I want to display "1,2,3 ... last Page Number (20)" same vice versa
5. on load Previous Button Should be hidden when ever next page is clicked it has to be enabled.

Request to you please look into this and give some advice / suggestion on this.

**Should be Like Below**

[image]

[image: Vice Versa]

Appreciate your kind help !

Thanks

- **some code sample :**

  ```
      $(function () {
          var opts = {
          pageMax: 5,
          postsDiv: $('#posts'),
          dataUrl: "searchResult.json"
      }

      function range(i) { return i ? range(i - 1).concat(i) : [] }

      function loadPosts(posts) {
          opts.postsDiv.empty();
          posts.each(function () {
              var source = $("#post-template").html();
              var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
              var context = {
                  title: this.title,
                  desc: this.body,
              };
              var html = template(context);
              opts.postsDiv.append(html);
          });
      }

      function paginate(pageCount) {
          var source = $("#pagination-template").html();
          var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
          var context = { pages: range(pageCount) };
          var html = template(context);
          opts.postsDiv.after(html);

          function changePage(pageNumber) {
              pageItems.removeClass('active');
              pageItems.filter('[data-page="' + pageNumber + '"]').addClass('active');
              loadPosts(data.slice(pageNumber * opts.pageMax - opts.pageMax, pageNumber * opts.pageMax));
          }

          var pageItems = $('.pagination>li.pagination-page');

          pageItems.on('click', function () {
              changePage(this.getAttribute('data-page'));
          }).filter('[data-page="1"]').addClass('active');

          $('.pagination>li.pagination-prev').on('click', function () {
              gotoPageNumber = parseInt($('.pagination>li.active').attr('data-page')) - 1;
              if (gotoPageNumber <= 0) { gotoPageNumber = pageCount; }
              changePage(gotoPageNumber);
          });

          $('.pagination>li.pagination-next').on('click', function () {
              gotoPageNumber = parseInt($('.pagination>li.active').attr('data-page')) + 1;
              if (gotoPageNumber > pageCount) { gotoPageNumber = 1; }
              changePage(gotoPageNumber);
          });
      }

      $.ajax({
          dataType: 'json',
          url: opts.dataUrl,
          success: function (response_json) {
              data = $(response_json.records.page);
              dataCount = data.length;

              pageCount = Math.ceil(dataCount / opts.pageMax);

              if (dataCount > opts.pageMax) {
                  paginate(pageCount);
                  posts = data.slice(0, opts.pageMax);
              } else {
                  posts = data;
              }
              loadPosts(posts);
          }
      });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to solve a similar issue a few months ago. I found [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/kottenator/9d936eb3e4e3c3e02598) from kottenator.

Your range function is modified thusly, with `c` being the current page, and `m` your `pageCount`. Calls to the function have been modified a bit and a recursive call to your `paginate(...)` function is also added to recompute the tag after navigation (also, a branch was added to your DOM appending function calls, to modify the pagination tag, I used a ternary operator. There may be more elegant to achieve this).
[See this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/project/editor/Dzvzbd/#0)

```
function range(c,m) {
  var current = c || 1,
      last = m,
      delta = 2,
      left = current - delta,
      right = parseInt(current) + delta + 1,
      range = [],
      rangeWithEllipsis = [],
      l,
      t;

      range.push(1);
      for (var i = c - delta ; i <= c + delta ; i++) {
        if (i >= left && i < right && i < m && i > 1) {
          range.push(i);
        }
      }  
      range.push(m);

      for (var i of range) {
        if (l) {
          if (i - l === 2) {
            t = l+1;
            rangeWithEllipsis.push(t);
          } else if (i - l !== 1) {
            rangeWithEllipsis.push("...");
          }
        }
        rangeWithEllipsis.push(i);
        l = i;
      }
    return rangeWithEllipsis;
}
```

It doesn't solve exactly your problem per say, but it does paginate correctly.
If I have some time, I'll try and make it paginate the exact way you want to (it's really only about customizing the `delta`, `left` and `right` operand in the algorithm, and changing your pagination next and pagination prev event handler calls).

**Edit** I changed the algorithm to find the `left` and `right` boundary. Your `index.html` is also modified a bit.
The idea is to compute the left and right boundary by multiples of 5. You then create a range of the indexes to show and add an elipsis if the difference is too big. This should effectively solves your original problem.

**JavaScript**

```
getFirstDigits = (t) => {
 return parseInt(t.toString().slice(0,-1))
}

getLastDigit = (t) => {
 return parseInt(t.toString().slice(-1))
}

isMultipleOf5 = (t) => {
 return [0,5].reduce((res,curr)=>{
   return res = res || curr === getLastDigit(t);
 },false);
}

isBetween0and5 = (t) => {
  const _t = getLastDigit(t);
  return  _t < 5;
}

isBetween5and9 = (t) => {
  const _t = getLastDigit(t);
  return  _t => 5 && _t <= 9;
}

appendDigit = (t,d) => {
  return parseInt(getFirstDigits(t).toString() + d.toString())
}

getSecondRightMostDigit = (t) => {
  return parseInt(t.toString().slice(-2,-1))
}

incrementSecondDigit = (t) => {
  return t+10;
}

getLeft = (t) => {
  if(t>=10){
    if(isBetween0and5(t)) return appendDigit(t,0);
    else return appendDigit(t,5);
  } else {
    if (t<5) return 0;
    else return 5;
  }
}

getRight = (t) => {
  if(t<5) return 5;
  else if (t<10) return 10;
  else if(isBetween0and5(t)) return appendDigit(t,5)
  else return appendDigit(incrementSecondDigit(t),0);
}

function range(c,m) {
  var current = c || 1,
      last = m,
      delta = 2,
      left = getLeft(c),
      right = getRight(c),
      range = [],
      rangeWithEllipsis = [],
      l,
      t;

      var rightBoundary = right < 5 ? 5 : right;
      for (var i = left ; i < rightBoundary ; ++i) {
        if( i < m && i > 0) range.push(i);
      }  
      range.push(m);

      for (var i of range) {
        if (l) {
          if (i - l === 2) {
            t = l+1;
            rangeWithEllipsis.push(t);
          } else if (i - l !== 1){
            rangeWithEllipsis.push("...");
          }
        }
        rangeWithEllipsis.push(i);
        l = i;
      }
    return rangeWithEllipsis;
}
```

**HTML/HandleBars**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Handlebars Pagination</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="container">

    <div id="posts"></div>

    <script id="pagination-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="pagination-prev"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>

            {{#each pages}}
            <li class="pagination-page" data-page="{{this}}"><a href="#">{{this}}</a></li>
            {{/each}}

            <li class="pagination-next"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </script>


    <script id="post-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="score-structural score-column2-wideright search-listings post">
            <div class="score-right">
                <h4>{{record_count}}</h4>
                <h5 style="z-index: 1;">
                    <a href="#"> {{ title }} </a>
                </h5>
                <p style="z-index: 1;"> {{ desc }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </script>

</body>

</html>

<script>
     $(function () {
        var opts = {
            pageMax: 2,
            postsDiv: $('#posts'),
            dataUrl: "searchResult.json"
        }

        function loadPosts(posts) {
            opts.postsDiv.empty();
            posts.each(function () {
                var source = $("#post-template").html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                var context = {
                    title: this.title,
                    desc: this.body,
                };
                var html = template(context);
                opts.postsDiv.append(html);
            });
            hidePrev();
        }

        function hidePrev() { $('.pagination .pagination-prev').hide(); }
        function showPrev() { $('.pagination .pagination-prev').show(); }

        function hideNext() { $('.pagination .pagination-next').hide(); }
        function showNext() { $('.pagination .pagination-next').show(); }

        function paginate(page,pageCount) {
            var source = $("#pagination-template").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            var context = { pages: range(page,pageCount) };
            console.log(range(page,pageCount));
            var html = template(context);
            var paginationTag = opts.postsDiv.parent().find(".pagination");
            paginationTag.length > 0 ? paginationTag.replaceWith(html) : opts.postsDiv.before(html);

            function changePage(page) {
                pageItems.removeClass('active');
                pageItems.filter('[data-page="' + page + '"]').addClass('active');
                loadPosts(data.slice(page * opts.pageMax - opts.pageMax, page * opts.pageMax));
                paginate(page,pageCount);
                if (gotoPageNumber <= 1) {
                    hidePrev();
                }
            }

            var pageItems = $('.pagination>li.pagination-page');
            var pageItemsLastPage = $('.pagination li').length - 2;
            pageItems.removeClass('active');
            pageItems.filter('[data-page="' + page + '"]').addClass('active');

            pageItems.on('click', function () {
                getDataPageNo = this.getAttribute('data-page')
                console.log(getDataPageNo)
                changePage(getDataPageNo);
                if (getDataPageNo == 1) {
                    hidePrev()
                }
                else if (getDataPageNo == pageItemsLastPage) {
                    hideNext();
                }
                else {
                    showPrev();
                    showNext();
                }
            });

            $('.pagination>li.pagination-prev').on('click', function () {
                gotoPageNumber = parseInt($('.pagination>li.active').attr('data-page')) - 1;
                changePage(gotoPageNumber);
            });

            $('.pagination>li.pagination-next').on('click', function () {
                gotoPageNumber = parseInt($('.pagination>li.active').attr('data-page')) + 1;
                if (gotoPageNumber > pageCount) {
                    gotoPageNumber = 1;
                    showPrev();
                }
                changePage(gotoPageNumber);
            });
        }

        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: opts.dataUrl,
            success: function (response_json) {
                data = $(response_json.records.page);
                dataCount = data.length;

                pageCount = Math.ceil(dataCount / opts.pageMax);

                if (dataCount > opts.pageMax) {
                    paginate(1,pageCount);
                    posts = data.slice(0, opts.pageMax);
                } else {
                    posts = data;
                }
                loadPosts(posts);
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: check the codepen again. i used es6, you might have to convert these arrow functions for your project.

Comment: Error 404 - Couldn't load file contents. have u published ? try it once in private window

Comment: i can access it from a  private window.

Comment: the modified files are the ones shown in the answer. you could also copy and paste.

Comment: sure, tnx will give a try

Comment: :-) yes thanks its working in one way, will mark answer as correct