# How can I set the page number in List.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, listjs

I'm using the latest version of List.js (v1.5.0). I created a paginated list and I want that it starts showing a page that I chose (not the first). For example: I chose 3, I want that list starts showing page number 3. How can I set this page on JQuery? Thanks.

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: It's the first time I use this plug-in, so I don't know how to use it. The documentation doesn't give any explanation about it, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you need a plugin with a documentation then. could you post some of the code you've written?

Comment: Do you know some plug-in useful for paginated list, with a good documentation?

Comment: IMHO, you'd have to write the pagination algorithm yourself. I've answered another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45096144/pagination-functionality-using-handlebars-js/45140229#45140229) on pagination. eventually, the library you use isn't so important. it should integrate nicely with the rest of your app. the jumping on the 3rd page is really the easy part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way myself! List.js plug-in have show(i, page) method.
Ref: http://listjs.com/api/#show.
It has 2 parameters: "i" , that is the number of item of the list you want to show first, and "page", that is the number of items per page. So it shows the "page" number of items after the "i" item. So to select your page, you have to calculate the number of item you want to show! Example: I have a list of 18 items. Page is set to 6, so i have 3 pages. To set page 3 at first, I had to calculate what item is shown at first at that page (the item number 13), then i do show(13,6) and it's done!